# Binary tree inorder traversal using Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to implement an inorder traversal which in every stage I'll get the current node.
For example:

```
?- getnodesinorder(tree(1,nil,nil),X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- getnodesinorder(tree(5,tree(4,tree(1,nil,tree(3,tree(2,nil,nil),nil)),nil),tree(6,nil,nil)),X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 6 ;
false.
```

I've tried the next code:

```
getnodesinorder(tree(CurrentNode,nil,nil), CurrentNode).
getnodesinorder(tree(X, Left, nil), CurrentNode) :-
    getnodesinorder(Left, _ ),
    CurrentNode is X.
getnodesinorder(tree(X, nil, Right), CurrentNode) :-
    CurrentNode is X,
    getnodesinorder(Right, _ ).
getnodesinorder(tree(X, Left, Right), CurrentNode) :-
    getnodesinorder(Left, _ ),
    CurrentNode is X,
    getnodesinorder(Right, _ ).
```

So of course the base (1st example works) but when trying to run the 2nd one I  get

```
X=5;
false
```

as result. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because you're processing the left and right subtrees, but not doing anything with the values in them: `getnodesinorder(Left, _ )` just throws them away. So, your predicate only returns the top element.

Here's how you do an in-order traversal:

```
inorder(tree(_,L,_), X) :- inorder(L,X).
inorder(tree(X,_,_), X).
inorder(tree(_,_,R), X) :- inorder(R,X).
```

Example query:

```
?- inorder(tree(5,tree(4,tree(1,nil,tree(3,tree(2,nil,nil),nil)),nil),tree(6,nil,nil)),X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 6 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[test] λ = cat test.pl 
append([], Ys, Ys).
append([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :- append(Xs, Ys, Zs).

getnodesinorder(nil, []).

getnodesinorder(tree(X, Left, Right), R) :-
   getnodesinorder(Left,R1),
   getnodesinorder(Right,R2),
   append(R1,[X|R2],R).
```

Works for me

```
?-getnodesinorder(tree(5,tree(4,tree(1,nil,tree(3,tree(2,nil,nil),nil)),nil),tree(6,nil,nil)),X).
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6] ? 
yes
```

Comment: Okay,did that (see above edited) but now I just get X=5 and then false from some reason.

Comment: try my sample. always remember to use trace.

Comment: Yes but you have used a list. In your code X is a list that you build and in the end you have a list of the inorder traversal. I want something else. I want X to be a variable that gets all the right values. Like in the example, when I type ";" I want to get the next X (the next number of the inorder sequence).